# How can I retain Fragments and their data on both orientation change using BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

After following a couple of Youtube tutorials (eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPV8xA7m-iw) I was able to build an Activity with a BottomNavigationView, that switches between three different fragments.

I'm not sure if this is the best method to achieve my goals. I need three screens, one of which (ReportFragment) will have user entered data that I wish to remaining place as the user switches between fragments.

The difficulty I am having is also retaining the Fragment data on an orientation change.

Here is one of the Fragment codes, I have implemented onSavedInstanceState to recall the data the user has entered and it seems to work okay:

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment {

EditText textCheck;
EditText textCheck2;
EditText textCheck3;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, null);

    textCheck = view.findViewById(R.id.editName);
    textCheck2 = view.findViewById(R.id.editHaz);
    textCheck3 = view.findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       textCheck.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("name"));
       textCheck2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("haz"));
       textCheck3.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("notes"));
    }
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("name", textCheck.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("haz",  textCheck2.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("notes",  textCheck3.getText().toString());
}
```

}

Here is the Activity Code:

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private HomeFragement frag1;
    private ReportFragment frag2;
    private MapFragement frag3;


    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    private static final String TAG = "FeedActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            frag1 = new HomeFragement();
            frag2 = new ReportFragment();
            frag3 = new MapFragement();

            loadFragment(frag1);
        }
    }


    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    //.addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = frag1;

                break;
            case R.id.navigation_camera:
                fragment = frag2;

                break;
            case R.id.navigation_map:
                fragment = frag3;

                break;
        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of ways in an attempt to retain the original Fragment, one being onSavedInstanceState, as per other suggestions on Stack Overflow. However during execution I receive an error regarding a null reference to navigation:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putInt("opened_fragment", navigation.getSelectedItemId());

}
```

as well as using the following code up in the OnCreate Method in in the if(onSavedInstanceState == null) statement:

```
navigation.setSelectedItemId(savedInstanceState.getInt("opened_fragment"));
```

The app currently correctly switches between the three fragments and retains the data as it needs to, until an orientation change occurs. The displayed fragment reverts back to frag1, and can no longer switch between fragments (I'm guessing it is something to do with the setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener??).

I am new to Android development.

EDIT: Now using a ViewPager which handles the the issues above

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found *a* solution myself. It appears to work, and give the functionality I need. However I would love some feedback from any experts as to whether it is the *right* solution.

The solution uses the fragment 'tag' assigned when using getSupportFragmentManager().replace, and checks if there has been a previous version of the fragment loaded. I'm not confident my logic in onNavigationItemSelected() is great but would love any feedback/criticism

Updated FeedActivity.Java:

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ReportFragment frag2;
private MapFragement frag3;
private HomeFragement frag1;

BottomNavigationView navigation;

private static final String TAG = "FeedActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        frag1 = new HomeFragement();
        frag2 = new ReportFragment();
        frag3 = new MapFragement();
    }
    loadFragment(frag1, "home");

}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String tagID){
if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tagID)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

    return true;
}
return false;
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tagID = null;
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            Fragment cachedFragment1 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("home");
            if (cachedFragment1 != null){
                fragment = cachedFragment1;
            }
            else{
            fragment = new HomeFragement();
            }
           tagID = "home";
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_camera:
            Fragment cachedFragment2 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("cam");
            if (cachedFragment2 != null){
                fragment = cachedFragment2;
            }
            else{
                fragment = new ReportFragment();
            }
            tagID = "cam";
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_map:
            Fragment cachedFragment3 = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("map");
            if (cachedFragment3 != null){
                fragment = cachedFragment3;
            }
            else{
                fragment = new MapFragement();
            }
            tagID = "map";
            break;
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment, tagID);
}}
```